# SageMaker: TypeError: Object of type Join is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to build a SM pipeline for a computer vision model.
The data is images stored in S3 bucket. I did the preprocessing using ScriptProcessor and now am trying to build the estimator.
Preprocessing works alright. But the estimator part is giving me TypeError: Object of type Join is not JSON serializable: error.

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow


output_config = preprocessing_job_description["ProcessingOutputConfig"]
for output in output_config["Outputs"]:
    if output["OutputName"] == "train_data":
        preprocessed_training_data = output["S3Output"]["S3Uri"]
    if output["OutputName"] == "valid_data":
        preprocessed_test_data = output["S3Output"]["S3Uri"]

s3_train = "s3://bucketname/image_data/train/"
s3_val = "s3://bucketname/image_data/val/"


tf_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point="train.py",
                          sagemaker_session=sess,
                          role=role,
                          instance_count=1, 
                          instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
                          # output_path = "/opt/ml/processing/output",
                          model_dir="s3://bucketname/image_data/output",
                          py_version='py37',
                          framework_version='2.4', 
                          hyperparameters={'epochs': epochs,
                                           'learning_rate': learning_rate, 
                                           'train_batch_size': 64,
                                          },
                          metric_definitions=metrics_definitions,
                          script_mode=True,
                          max_run=7200 # max 2 hours * 60 minutes seconds per hour * 60 sec per minutes
                         )

tf_estimator.fit({"train": preprocessed_training_data})
```

This gives me the following error:

---

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 36                          )
> 37
> ---> 38 tf_estimator.fit({"train": preprocessed_training_data})
> 39 # tf_estimator.fit({"train": s3_train})
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/workflow/pipeline_context.py
> in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
> 207             return self_instance.sagemaker_session.context
> 208
> --> 209         return run_func(*args, **kwargs)
> 210
> 211     return wrapper
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py in
> fit(self, inputs, wait, logs, job_name, experiment_config)
> 976         self._prepare_for_training(job_name=job_name)
> 977
> --> 978         self.latest_training_job = _TrainingJob.start_new(self, inputs, experiment_config)
> 979         self.jobs.append(self.latest_training_job)
> 980         if wait:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py in
> start_new(cls, estimator, inputs, experiment_config)    1806
> train_args = cls._get_train_args(estimator, inputs, experiment_config)
> 1807
> -> 1808         estimator.sagemaker_session.train(**train_args)    1809     1810         return cls(estimator.sagemaker_session,
> estimator._current_job_name)
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in
> train(self, input_mode, input_config, role, job_name, output_config,
> resource_config, vpc_config, hyperparameters, stop_condition, tags,
> metric_definitions, enable_network_isolation, image_uri,
> algorithm_arn, encrypt_inter_container_traffic, use_spot_instances,
> checkpoint_s3_uri, checkpoint_local_path, experiment_config,
> debugger_rule_configs, debugger_hook_config,
> tensorboard_output_config, enable_sagemaker_metrics,
> profiler_rule_configs, profiler_config, environment, retry_strategy)
> 592             encrypt_inter_container_traffic=encrypt_inter_container_traffic,
> 593             use_spot_instances=use_spot_instances,
> --> 594             checkpoint_s3_uri=checkpoint_s3_uri,
> 595             checkpoint_local_path=checkpoint_local_path,
> 596             experiment_config=experiment_config,
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in
> _intercept_create_request(self, request, create, func_name)    4201         """    4202         region = self.boto_session.region_name
> -> 4203         sts_client = self.boto_session.client(    4204             "sts", region_name=region, endpoint_url=sts_regional_endpoint(region)
> 4205         )
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in
> submit(request)
> 589             enable_network_isolation=enable_network_isolation,
> 590             image_uri=image_uri,
> --> 591             algorithm_arn=algorithm_arn,
> 592             encrypt_inter_container_traffic=encrypt_inter_container_traffic,
> 593             use_spot_instances=use_spot_instances,
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/json/**init**.py in dumps(obj, skipkeys,
> ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators,
> default, sort_keys, **kw)
> 236         check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
> 237         separators=separators, default=default, sort_keys=sort_keys,
> --> 238         **kw).encode(obj)
> 239
> 240
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in encode(self, o)
> 199         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
> 200         if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
> --> 201             chunks = list(chunks)
> 202         return ''.join(chunks)
> 203
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in _iterencode(o,
> _current_indent_level)
> 429             yield from _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level)
> 430         elif isinstance(o, dict):
> --> 431             yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
> 432         else:
> 433             if markers is not None:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in _iterencode_dict(dct,
> _current_indent_level)
> 403                 else:
> 404                     chunks = _iterencode(value, _current_indent_level)
> --> 405                 yield from chunks
> 406         if newline_indent is not None:
> 407             _current_indent_level -= 1
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in _iterencode_dict(dct,
> _current_indent_level)
> 403                 else:
> 404                     chunks = _iterencode(value, _current_indent_level)
> --> 405                 yield from chunks
> 406         if newline_indent is not None:
> 407             _current_indent_level -= 1
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in _iterencode(o,
> _current_indent_level)
> 436                     raise ValueError("Circular reference detected")
> 437                 markers[markerid] = o
> --> 438             o = _default(o)
> 439             yield from _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level)
> 440             if markers is not None:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in default(self, o)
> 177
> 178         """
> --> 179         raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '
> 180                         f'is not JSON serializable')
> 181
>
> TypeError: Object of type Join is not JSON serializable

I have tried changing all the arguments I have given for the estimator. Sometimes enabling them and sometimes disabling them.
--> 594 checkpoint_s3_uri=checkpoint_s3_uri,
If this is the origin, I have tried giving it also.

No idea where I'm messing up.
I'm using

```
sagemaker 2.94.0
Python3 Data Science kernel
boto3 '1.24.8'
```

Comment: Why are you using processing job description here? If you are using pipelines, you can pass the output of the processing step to the estimator step - 

```
TrainingInput(
                s3_data=step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs[
                    "train"
                ].S3Output.S3Uri,
                content_type="text/csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, try to use `PipelineSession` instead of a normal Session object:

```py
from sagemaker.workflow.pipeline_context import PipelineSession

tf_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point="train.py",
                          sagemaker_session=PipelineSession()
)
```

https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/3860

Comment: Using PipelineSession doesn't resolve the issue

Comment: Using PipelineSession solved my issue. I wasted an entire day before I got solution. Thanks @maslick